# Replacing @username with Profile Link

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

First of all, I use the below code:

```
$input = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i',
                  '$1<a href="http://www.example.com/profile.php?u=$2">@$2</a>',
                   $input);
```

to convert @username to their profile link but i want to do real validations for it too. I want to convert the @username to link only if that username is already in my database (and if possible show their Profile name instead of showing username extracted from database like `<a href="profile.php?u=$1">$name</a>` or something like it)

Here are my Database Structure:

```
Table: `user`
Rows: `username` - for username
`name` to store user's real name
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: take a look at `preg_replace_callback`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php . You can write your pattern like this too: `/@(?<!\S@)(\w+)/` *(it's more efficient to start with a litteral than starting with an alternation)*